# Simple drop-down "list" items (inside a html "body") --- content (un)hiding upon click --- Not a navigation bar, no redirect, no menu, no forms

Tags: theming

I would like to ask if it were possible to have certain content (nothing too special, just regular lines of text with standard formatting) on a html article, like e.g. ordered in a list, which can be **unfolded (or hidden again) by a mouse-click**?

When searching information on this, I easily come by navigation drop-down menu's; but a navigation side-bar or top-bar is ***not*** what I am looking for.
I have found [another question asking for something similar](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135215/is-possible-to-display-view-contents-in-a-drop-down-select-list), but wanting to be redericted to another page (similar to a navigation menu), that is also ***not*** what I want to do: I do ***not*** want to navigate to another page.

I would simply like a drop-down "list" **inside a html's "body" article**. The visitor should be able to open or close these "frames" or "list items", e.g. by clicking on the title or on a list button. I am just looking for a "1-level-depth" list.

It would be nice if the items had a title and a number, ordered vertically, like a regular ordered list:

1. ***>click to unfold<*** List item 1
2. ***>click to unfold<*** List item 2
3. ***>click to unfold<*** ...

If, for example you would click on list item 1, the content of list item 1 would show:

1. ***>clicked, click to hide content again<*** List item 1 
   *<<< Content of list item 1, which is just standard lines of text, perhaps with standart formatting. >>>*
2. ***>click to (un)fold<*** List item 2
3. ***>click to (un)fold<*** ...

The text I have put between **">"..."<"**, is just to clarify; isn't specifically needed. This could just be a triangular list bullet for example, which could just change by pointing downwards when clicked.

Is this possible by using a Drupal module, or perhaps just via html code?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated,

Vincent Verheyen.

P.S.: I am very new to Drupal and understand the basics such as installing modules.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. This appears to be more like a jQuery issue to me. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701915/show-hide-text-using-jquery

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot @Wtower. Is it easy to implement this into a Drupal html article? Can I just the jQuery codes over there, or should I use some kind of a module? --- I will look definitely into jQuery, it seems like a very good trail.

Comment: I am glad. This question is not Drupal per se, jQuery is a common and powerful JS library which is included within Drupal as you probably already figured out.

Answer (score 1):

@Wtower's help above makes this pretty straightforward. Drupal (I am using 7) can use these jQuery codes without any additional install.

One can just put the following right inside a drupal "node", such as a standard article. This solution works for list items; the following is to be implemented [I used ordered lists (ol) in my example]:

```
<style>#toggler li:hover {text-decoration: underline; cursor: default}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#toggler li").click(function(){jQuery(this).next().slideToggle("slow"); return false;}).next().hide();});</script>

    <ol id="toggler">
    <li>List tem 1.</li>
    <div>Content of list item 1.</div>
    <li>List item 2.</li>
    <div>Content of list item 2.</div>
    </ol>
```

---

I haven't looked at triangular (changing upon revealing or hiding content) list bullets yet.

If you want other items than list items, look here:

- http://renaudjoubert.com/fr/node/56
- http://triq.net/articles/hide-and-slide-drupal-content-jquery

Answer (score 1):

I think you can acheive what you want with the https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group module. Enable to module and go to you content type, add the different groups you want to collapse/expand and add one or more fields inside.

You can change how you want to users to see the fields groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Maarten! This seems very interesting. However, I am not completely sure yet how to use this. Might I ask you very friendly for some more clarification? --- **Field group**-module is installed. My content type (or node) is called [Article]. --- In Drupal's `(Structure)`->`(Content types)`->`[Article]`->`(Manage fields)`; I can notice the "Add new field" option. Should I use this, and how?

Comment: @VincentVerheyen this is a nice approach, it would require to organize content into fields, which might be better depending on the requirements.

Comment: When the field group module is installed and enabled, you should be able to add groups. This video explains it very well http://youtu.be/5GU_tb4K-f4. At 1m57 it starts where you are http://youtu.be/5GU_tb4K-f4?t=1m57s. If you don't see the add group, something went wrong when installing the module and you should re-install it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility just for the record (more intermediate approach) would be to organize the collapsible content into nodes, then use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) in order to present the relevant nodes in a page.

Then you can either:

- Use a module such as [Views Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion)
- or theme the view to [facilitate collapse.js](https://www.drupal.org/node/1169632)

so that the views rows be collapsible.